# getint vague definition in k&r, weird behaviour of ungetch in it

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have a big problem understanding several lines from the following code (numbers marked in comments):

First - the code of a loop that fills an array with the input data:

```
int n, array[SIZE], getint(int *);
for (n = 0; n < SIZE && getint(&array[n]) != EOF; n++)
      ;
```

Now the function definition:

```
/* getint:  get next integer from input into *pn */

int getint(int *pn)

{

int c, sign;

while (isspace(c = getch()))   /* skip white space */
        ;

if (!isdigit(c) && c != EOF && c != '+' && c != '-') {
        ungetch(c); /* [1] */ /* it is not a number */
        return 0;  /* [2] */
}
sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;
if (c == '+' || c == '-')
        c = getch();
for (*pn = 0; isdigit(c); c = getch())
        *pn = 10 * *pn + (c - '0'); [3]
*pn *= sign;
if (c != EOF) /* [4a] */
        ungetch(c); /* [4b] */
return c; 
}



#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE];      /* buffer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0;           /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
{
   return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c)     /* push character back on input */
{
   if(bufp >= BUFSIZE)
      printf(" ungetch too many characters\n");

   else
      buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

So:

[1] I've read similar posts here, that taking back such an unwanted char somehow blocks the buffer, so that we need to clear it using another function. For me it's strange that is not included in K&R and authors don't even mention the necessity to use it?

[2] Why do we return 0? Does that stop the whole main() program? Or does it simply put 0 in an array ? ( getint(&array[n] ) ?

[3] Why do we need to implement such a formula to calculate "big numbers" ? Since that function just gets numbers one after the other (getchar not getword) and then create "big number" by means of several single integers.

[4a][4b] Why does it ungetch if c != EOF? This condition is fulfilled most of the time, so we would end up with rejecting every inputted number?

Thanks in advance for answering!

Comment: K&R is not a good source for learning ALL the tidbits of the language.  You'd be better served with a more detailed text or read the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It doesn't, and even if it did with some other library, not with these 2 functions
2. Nope. It simply returns zero and leaves the integer uninitialized (this case isn't handled in the loop)
3. What do you mean? This is simply how you calculate an integer from it's digits.
4. It will simply `ungetch` the character that was trailing the integer the function just read and processed - unless there was no character but an end of stream marked by `EOF`. That marker isn't returned to the buffer.

Comment: Answers 1, 2 - Thanks, no more questions about them. But for the 3 - I mean according to the for loop - getint is provided with arguments from an array one by one place in it. So apparently number 123 would be passed as array[0] = 1; array[1] = 2; array[2] = 3. Am I right? Coming to 4 answer -> if the input is like 12z3 I understand it will ungetch every element one after the other ?

Comment: To 3: `getint` parses integers, not digits, from the input stream. Thus when it sees a `"123"` (with nothing in between), it'll store a `123` to `*pn` (and thus to the current element in `array`). How it does is a simple algorithm: it'll read chars as long as they're digits, and for each digit `*pn` is first multiplied by 10 and the digit is added to it.

Comment: @PeterKowalski: With "12z3" or similar, it'll first read '1', then '2' (and store 12 to `*pn` accordingly), and when it reads a 'z' which is not a digit, it "ungetches" it back to the buffer. Then the function returns. (It will not get past the 'z' in subsequent runs, but will simply keep returning 0 as long as you'll call it.)

Comment: (I see now that you might've referred to this behavior (of not getting past invalid input) in your first question.)

Comment: Thanks again. But another question - so numbers satisfy ONLY the for loop condition (for (*pn = 0; isdigit(c), c = getch()) ??
And they do not satisfy if (c != EOF) condition? How is that possible?

Comment: (c != EOF) is true while there's still more to read from the stream. That may or may not be the case after a number is read, depending on whether it was the last thing there is on the stream.